# Aligning Images beside eachother

Tags: html, css, image

I can start this post by saying to the few people who've might come over my other post about this. And yes, I am asking it another time, Because it's a different problem, but in the same category.

It seems like aligning text under images ruins everything when I try to fit it. Here is a picture of the site without the text under the images: 
[Image of the Crew Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVQfd.png)

Here is the code for the crew page, before the text:

```
<section id="crew">
    <h1 style="color:#fff">Crew</h1>
<br>
<div style="justify-content:center" class="container5">

    <img hspace="20" class="crew grow" src="http://nexuscoding.net/5h0GIcqwYiXafUkKEGYy.png">
    <img hspace="20" class="crew grow" src="http://nexuscoding.net/5h0GIcqwYiXafUkKEGYy.png">
    <img hspace="20" class="crew grow" src="http://nexuscoding.net/5h0GIcqwYiXafUkKEGYy.png">
    <br><br><br><br><br>

    <img hspace="20" class="crew grow" src="http://nexuscoding.net/5h0GIcqwYiXafUkKEGYy.png">
    <img hspace="20" class="crew grow" src="http://nexuscoding.net/5h0GIcqwYiXafUkKEGYy.png">
    <img hspace="20" class="crew grow" src="http://nexuscoding.net/5h0GIcqwYiXafUkKEGYy.png">

    </div>        
</section>
```

Now here is an image of the page after I've tried fitting text under the images:
[Image of the Crew Page after Text has been added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpMSn.png)

Here is the code for the section after the text has been added:

```
<section id="crew">
    <h1 style="color:#fff">Crew</h1>
<br>
<div style="justify-content:center" class="container5">

    <img hspace="20" class="crew grow" src="http://nexuscoding.net/5h0GIcqwYiXafUkKEGYy.png">
    <figcaption>Some Text</figcaption>
    <img hspace="20" class="crew grow" src="http://nexuscoding.net/5h0GIcqwYiXafUkKEGYy.png">
    <figcaption>Some Text</figcaption>
    <img hspace="20" class="crew grow" src="http://nexuscoding.net/5h0GIcqwYiXafUkKEGYy.png">
    <figcaption>Some Text</figcaption>
    <br><br><br><br><br>

    <img hspace="20" class="crew grow" src="http://nexuscoding.net/5h0GIcqwYiXafUkKEGYy.png">
    <figcaption>Some Text</figcaption>
    <img hspace="20" class="crew grow" src="http://nexuscoding.net/5h0GIcqwYiXafUkKEGYy.png">
    <figcaption>Some Text</figcaption>
    <img hspace="20" class="crew grow" src="http://nexuscoding.net/5h0GIcqwYiXafUkKEGYy.png">
    <figcaption>Some Text</figcaption>

    </div>        
</section>
```

So as you can see, the text ruins everything, and I just don't understand why it keeps doing this. Any thoughts? Thanks for taking your time reading the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `<figcaption>` is `display: block` by default, which means it takes up the whole width of the parent element. I suggest you wrap an image with a corresponding caption in a div.

```css
.cont {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="crew">
    <h1 style="color: black">Crew</h1>
<br>
<div style="justify-content:center" class="container5">
<div class=cont>
    <img hspace="20" class="crew grow" src="http://nexuscoding.net/5h0GIcqwYiXafUkKEGYy.png">
    <figcaption>Some Text</figcaption>
    </div>
    <div class=cont>
    <img hspace="20" class="crew grow" src="http://nexuscoding.net/5h0GIcqwYiXafUkKEGYy.png">
    <figcaption>Some Text</figcaption>
    </div>
    <div class=cont>
    <img hspace="20" class="crew grow" src="http://nexuscoding.net/5h0GIcqwYiXafUkKEGYy.png">
    <figcaption>Some Text</figcaption>
    </div>
    <br><br><br><br><br>

<div class=cont>
    <img hspace="20" class="crew grow" src="http://nexuscoding.net/5h0GIcqwYiXafUkKEGYy.png">
    <figcaption>Some Text</figcaption>
    </div>
    <div class=cont>
    <img hspace="20" class="crew grow" src="http://nexuscoding.net/5h0GIcqwYiXafUkKEGYy.png">
    <figcaption>Some Text</figcaption>
    </div>
    <div class=cont>
    <img hspace="20" class="crew grow" src="http://nexuscoding.net/5h0GIcqwYiXafUkKEGYy.png">
    <figcaption>Some Text</figcaption>
    </div>

    </div>        
</section>
```

See this [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/xk2pkjwv/)

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning put both  and  tag inside  tag
(each one in figure) like this:

```html
<figure>
  <img src="test.bmp" />
  <figcaption>
    hELLO
  </figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="test2.bmp" />
  <figCAPTION>
    hELLO
  </figCAPTION>
  </figure>
```

then   set the style of the the  tag to be floating on left like this:

```css
figure{float:left;}
```

and you should get what do you want.
By the way see (block and inline tags) in HTML and (float,position) in CSS.